# Import multiple TXT/CSV into one Excel sheet but each file in next column

Tags: vba, excel

I have one folder with TXT files (one column). I need to import them in one Worksheet but each file should be in new column. Would be great to add a file name as a header.

I'm trying to increase `cl` element before new file is open. Is is good direction?

```
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)
i = i + 1
```

How to modify below code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("d:\Projects\Data\")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)

            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close


    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem a good match to the question: it would help to post some sample date from one of your input files, and also show how it should look on the worksheet.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the best way here to share a sample data. Lets try with this image: [link]http://i66.tinypic.com/a3jdde.png Column A contain sample from 1st file. Columns C-E what I'm expecting to see after combining with other files. Filenames are optional. Data should start from column A. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("d:\Projects\Data\")

    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each file In folder.Files

        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        cl.Value = file.Name
        i = 1

        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            cl.Offset(i, 0).Value = FileText.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        FileText.Close

        Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)
    Next file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you Tim!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your text file data all fits neatly in one column.  If you're iterating over rows and columns like that, I always preferred to use the `Cells(x, y).Value` syntax.

No guarantee that it's the most efficient way to do things, but this seems like a simple enough procedure that performance won't matter too much.

You could adapt your code to do something like this:

```
    Dim RowIndex As Long  'Excel Rows need the Long data type
    Dim ColumnIndex As Integer ' Not as many columns, so use Integer

    ' Start at column 1.
    ColumnIndex = 1

    ' Do the rest of your file I/O and split into the Items array.

    ' Here's your column header:
    Cells(1, ColumnIndex).Value = file.Name

    ' Start the actual data in row 2.
    RowIndex = 2
    For (i = 0 to UBound(Items))
        Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex).Value = Items(i)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Next i

    ' When you're all done, advance ColumnIndex so the next time through
    ' the loop you're outputting on the next Column.
    ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex + 1
```

This should be functionally identical to the `Offset` syntax you're using, but I've found that using `Cells` makes it more obvious what index (row or column or both) you're iterating over.